# haproxy allow other backend even if few backends are down

Tags: haproxy

I want haproxy to route to the other backends even if few backends are down ..

Config :

```
backend a
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie SRV_ID prefix
        server svrstatic 192.168.1.100:10511 cookie A check
backend b
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie SRV_ID prefix
        server svrstatic 192.168.1.100:10511 cookie A check
```

Logs:

```
hascripts@vv1    | [ALERT] 081/151552 (9) : backend 'b' has no server available!
```

Also retry to resolve hostnames and servers after specified interval.